# Apple Script: 'activate' an application in fullscreen

Tags: macos, applescript, script

Im trying to run `tell application "X" to activate` on an application that is running in fullscreen, but its not working. Any ideas on how I can work around this and give focus to a running app in fullscreen?

Comment: If I put e.g. Calendar in full screen and run `tell application "Calendar" to activate` in Script Editor, it activates it taking me to it. So instead of or in addition to `X` in `tell application "X" to activate`, please provide additional relevant details about the application you're trying to activate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have the *"When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"* option on?

In which case, you can either toggle it, or use an additional `tell` block:

```
tell application "System Events" to click UI element "X" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
```

A bit ugly, but works. Quoted myself from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462452/501645).

Answer (score -1):

Allow the Script Editor to access Accessibility in System Preferences, & try this script. You should define the application name properly.

```
set MyApps to {"Google Chrome", "Skype", "Finder"}

repeat with MyApp in MyApps

tell application MyApp

    activate

    delay 3

    tell application "System Events" to tell process MyApp

        set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true

    end tell

end tell

end repeat
```

or if you have a single application then

```
tell application "Safari"

activate

delay 3

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"

    set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true

  end tell

end tell
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how to put a window into full screen view, he is trying to activate a window that is already in full screen view. Additionally, a three second delay is an unreasonable amount if a delay is necessary. One should use a repeat loop with a small delay, e.g `delay 0.1` or less while checking for the existence of the target object. E.g. `repeat until (exists window 1 of application "APP_NAME")`, etc. That said, your answer doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: In addition to what has been said above, which I wholeheartedly agree with, you should not put a `tell app "System Events"` block inside another `tell app...` block as you've done in both scripts.  `tell` one application what to do, then `end tell`.  Then `tell` the other application what to do, and so on.  This, of course, doesn't apply to `tell process` blocks, which _must_ be inside a `tell app "System Events"` block (as you've correctly done), since processes belong to System Events.  However, applications belong to AppleScript and nothing else.