# How to switch between fullscreen apps with Control + Number shortcut?

Tags: macbook-pro, application-switcher

I have Macbook Pro Ventura 13.1 and I would like to know how to switch between fullscreen apps with keyboard shortcut e.g. Control + Number (As with Desktops, as how i3wm). What do I need to configure or to install to realise it?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
Fullscreen desktops have no number. They start from 'one to the right' of your current highest number, no matter what that is.

If you drag to re-arrange, they still don't fill a numbered Space, the numbers shift around them…

[image]

You can, of course, use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>→</kbd>  or  <kbd>←</kbd>  but you'll need to start from a 'real' number nearby; or  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>↑</kbd>  to reveal all Desktops across the top of your screen [as in the partial image above], then click.

<sup>One of many reasons I never use fullscreen;)</sup>

Comment: Thank you :)
I think I will not use fullscreen for now :D

Answer (score 0):

There's an ad hoc solution to this:

1. Install [Raycast](https://www.raycast.com/) (or any similar app, like Alfred)
2. Set a shortcut to the desired app, such as Terminal, Mail etc.
3. Make sure the "When switching to an application..." option is on

Then, if you only have one full-screen window of your app, you can press the shortcut and it'll switch desktop to that window.

Caveats:

1. Doesn't work without the "When switching..." option (I find this option really annoying but it's probably not a big deal to others)
2. Doesn't work with two full-screen windows of the same app
3. Need to manually create shortcuts for each app

Overall, this is not so bad, but yeah, I wish there was a native solution, along the lines of a checkbox somewhere, "Assign numbers to full-screen application desktops". This solution works OK if you only have a couple apps that you use on a daily basis in full-screen format. For example, I have normal desktop spaces on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>,..., and Terminal on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

**UPD** I figured a way to switch to a full-screen app using a shortcut without toggling the "When switching..." option, so, in other words, solved the first caveat!

Here's an AppleScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

# Required parameters:
# @raycast.schemaVersion 1
# @raycast.title activate Terminal
# @raycast.mode silent

# Optional parameters:
# @raycast.icon

on run
  tell application "Terminal" to activate
  tell application "System Events" to click UI element "Terminal" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
end run
```

You can save it and create a shortcut to run it (using, again, one of the launchers, like Raycast), and this comes as close as possible to being able to switch directly to the full-screen app.

I have left the Raycast parameters in case you'd use it, but you can delete every line that starts with `#`, except `#!`.